# Remove element from list if list of sub strings in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

Fairly a newbie in Python3. Was wondering what the most efficient way is to accomplish this, i.e. if a directory listing contains a sub directory, then remove that item from the directory listing.

```
dirs = [ "/mnt/user/dir1", "/mnt/user/dir1/filea", "/mnt/user/dir2", "/mnt/user/dir3", "/mnt/user/dir4" ]
exclude_dirs = [ "/mnt/user/dir1", "/mnt/user/dir3" ]
```

if any element of exclude_dirs occurs in dirs, then remove that item from dirs. In above example, the matching would be a substring match, i.e. I'd expect these elements to be removed from dirs:

```
"/mnt/user/dir1"
"/mnt/user/dir1/filea"
"/mnt/user/dir3"
```

Help! :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
>>> [d for d in dirs if not any([
    d == e or d.startswith(f'{e}/') for e in exclude_dirs])]
['/mnt/user/dir2', '/mnt/user/dir4']
```

Comment: Thank you Pierre! I wasn't quite acquainted with "any." I code in Go, and thought about doing it in my comfort zone. Only way to learn a great language like Python is to practice. :) Love it, and with concurrency in it, super fast to code what I wanted... A concurrent way of indexing all files on my NAS with sha256 hashes, so I can see how much of it is dupe.